# How to rename a table in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to rename the table 'folks' to 'users'.
How does it work?

Comment: Your question name does not match your description.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, sorry.

Comment: Poor try to get some rep with a simple question that has been asked back in the stoneage already. You have a gold badge and > 1k rep. You are experienced enough to know that this kind of duplicate question asking + self-answering is not how Stackoverflow works.

Comment: @DanFromGermanylol, first of first, i was searching if the question exists, but nothing came up. Second it is even desired from SO to answer own questions Q&A style. Go ahead and create a new question and look what the text on the bottom says. "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style"

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use `ALTER TABLE` with `RENAME TO`.

**Syntax:**

```
ALTER TABLE <Tablename>
RENAME TO <new Tablename>;
```

**Example:**

```
ALTER TABLE folks
RENAME TO users;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rename the column and also change its type

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName] CHANGE [Column] [ColumnName] [New type];
```

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE folks CHANGE FolkAddress Address VARCHAR(1024);
```

Comment: But in which step are you renaming it to `users`?

Comment: I'm not, your problem description does not match the question name.